# Выделение цифры из числа в двоичном виде и ее замена (c-sharp)

Tags: c#

по условию задачи необходимо ввести число в бинарном представлении, затем третий бит заменить на 1, т.е. ввел, например, 110111 - получил 111111, ввел 111111 - программа выдала число без изменений и т.п.

Только начал изучать шарп (мой первый язык), поэтому нужно решить задачу самым простым способом (в интернете нашел только сложные решения с использованием массивов и прочих вещей, которые я еще не изучил)

Третий бит  найти и изменить на 1 я смог, но как теперь его вернуть в само число?
Вот код моей программы:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

class Prog
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string A = Interaction.InputBox("Введите число в двоичном представлении", "Ввод числа");
        int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(A, 2);
        string B = Convert.ToString(num1, 2);
        string C = (" " + B[2]);
        int num2 = Int32.Parse(C);
        int num3 = (num2 == 0 ? ++num2 : num2);
        MessageBox.Show(" " + num3);
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> затем третий бит заменить на 1, т.е. ввел, например, 110111 - получил
>   111111

А вы уверены, что отсчет битов ведется слева? Обычно считают справа, как разряды в обычных десятичных числах.

То, как вы сделали, через строковое представление числа - лютейший костыль. Биты в числе устанавливаются/снимаются с помощью побитовых операторов `|`, `&` и `^`.

Для вашего случая (установить третий бит в числе в единицу):

```
// получаете число любым способом
int number = 123;
// сокращенная форма
number |= (1 << 2);
// полная форма
number = number | (1 << 2);
```

Выражение `1 << 2` означает, что нужно взять число `0b00000001`, сдвинуть в нем все разряды на 2 влево (получится `0b00000100`).
Дальше с помощью оператора `|` выполняется побитовое сложение с вашим числом (по-сути, установка третьего бита в числе), и результат помещается в то же самое число.